# Konsole does not participate in either clipboards for one user

Tags: xfce, clipboard, konsole

We use Debian 9 with the Xfce desktop at work. One user uses both `xfce4-terminal` and `konsole`. For some reason he cannot copy text from Konsole using neither mouse selection and middle click nor the clipboard via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Pasting into Konsole works fine, though.

I have tried this on a similarly configured machine using my user profile, and I do not exhibit this problem. Where can I diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Primary buffer is not the same as clipboard buffer.

You can use [autocutsel](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/) to synchronize these buffers:

```
autocutsel -cutbuffer 0 -f -s PRIMARY
autocutsel -f -s CLIPBOARD
```